# how to append the object into empty array

Tags: javascript

This is my code. I written the code in console

[image]

---

The expected output as follows:

```js
var myArray = [{
    fruit: 'apple',
    price: '90',
    qty: '6'
  },
  {
    fruit: 'mango',
    price: '100',
    qty: '6'
  },
  {
    fruit: 'pineapple',
    price: '50',
    qty: '1'
  }
];
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) -> [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Alternative link : [Please no images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: `const arr = f.map((fruit,i) => ({fruit:fruit, price:p[i], qty:q[i]}))`

Comment: @SanketJagadale Please next time make a more complete question for us

Comment: @mplungjan can u help me for solving this array data represent into html table?

Comment: Ask a new question- you know now what we expect

Comment: @mplungjan - I m really sry for asking incomplete question

Comment: No problem- you are new

Comment: @mplungjan yes i just started my career in junior software developer

Comment: @mplungjan how to represent this array data into html table?

Comment: What did you try? You need a loop. I like to map html from array

Comment: @mplungjan I want to insert this all data of fruits ,price and qty into html table.. this is my task

Comment: I understand. Now write some code and ask a new question when you get stuck. Make a [mcve] and use the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for actual code, html and css

Answer (score 0):

such example:

```js
 myArray .push({ fruit: 'apple', price: '90', qty: '6' })
```

Comment: thanks but i want all object in my array

Comment: @SanketJagadale I this the `push` is the important point here that Peter forgot to tell you